# How to Sign apk programmatically in java / by using command line

Tags: java, phonegap-build, android-install-apk, jarsigner, zipalign

I am working on phonegap project. I have one apk file which is working fine and installing properly on android device, but I want to do some modification in that apk file, for that what i am doing is, just renaming it's extention from apk to zip and simply extracting it, and doing some changes in HTML file which is located at asset/www folder. And after modifying all necessary changes again compressing that folder back to zip and again back to apk. I just want to install that modified apk file onto android device. But while installing it is parsing properly but getting error Apk not installed, I think I am getting this error because that modified `apk is not signed and zipalign`.

So my main question is, how can i signed my apk using jarsigner and zipalign mechanism is there any java code or command so that i can achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Comment: I have gone through whatever steps are given in this link, but for the second last step I am getting exception saying, 

"Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to deduce Min API Level from APK's AndroidManifest.xml. Use --min-sdk-version to override.
"
Unable to understand it, where i am doing mistake. @GoneUp

Comment: As the error says, check your manifest if the minsdk value is there. If not, add it or specify it as a additional command line option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @GoneUp, it worked.

Comment: Okay, I added the solution as a answer. Would be nice if you can accept it as a solution to give me some reputation ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to follow the guide on https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually.